# Unable to find location updates when an application is running in the background

Tags: android, gps, android-service

I am trying to create an application where I want to run the Android application in the background continuously.

I have created the service class to run the application in the background for location update.
The service is not running continuously, but after some time it stops. Below is the Boot receiver class which starts the service.

I have put both classes Service and Boot Receiver class.

What am I doing wrong or have I missed anything?

```
/********************Boot receiver********************/

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("IntentReceiver", "Got intent " + intent.getAction() + " / data: " + intent.getDataString());

        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,MyService.class);

            PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(i);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**********************Myservice*********************/

import java.util.Date;

import com.safecell.dataaccess.InteruptionRepository;
import com.safecell.dataaccess.TempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository;
import com.safecell.model.SCProfile;
import com.safecell.model.SCWayPoint;
import com.safecell.receiver.LockReceiver;
import com.safecell.utilities.DateUtils;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.location.Location;

import android.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static LocationManager mlocManager;
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    public static double x=0.0 ,y=0.0,last_x=0.0,last_y=0.0;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static int j=0;
    public static TrackingScreenActivity trackingScreenActivity = null;
    public static TrackingService trackingService;
    static TempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository;
    double speed = 0.0;
    private float lastDistanceInMiles = 0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "start My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

        if(SplashScreenActivity.act_flag)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreenActivity.class);
            myStarterIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(myStarterIntent);
        }
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TRIP", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    }

    /***********************To insert a record in an nsqlite table**********************/

    private void insertWaypoint(Location location) {
        // InteruptionRepository
        tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository= new TempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository(
            getApplicationContext());

        double distanceInMiles = tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository.getDistanceDifference(location);

        //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
        //                "didf=f"+distanceInMiles,
        //                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        double timeDifference = tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository.getTimeDiffernce(currentTime);
        double avarageSpeed = tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository.getAvarageEstimatedSpeedForAutoTripStart();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TRIP", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        boolean isTripStarted = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isTripStarted", false);

        if (timeDifference != 0 && distanceInMiles!=0) {
            speed = distanceInMiles / timeDifference;
        }

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "didf=f"+speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        boolean background = true;
        if (isTripStarted)
        {
            AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

            SCWayPoint wayPoint =
                new SCWayPoint(0, 0,
                               DateUtils.getTimeStamp(currentTime),
                               location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), speed,
                               background);

            tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository.intsertWaypoint(wayPoint);
        }// if trip started

        // trackingScreenActivity.dismProgressDialog();
    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onlocationchnage");
            x=loc.getLatitude();
            y=loc.getLongitude();
            int d3= calcDistance(last_x,last_y,x,y);
            double speed;
            if (d3>20) {
                speed = d3/20;
            }
            else
            {
                speed=0.0;
            }
            j++;

            String Text ="My current location is: " +

            "Latitud1 = " +x +

            "Longitud1 = " +y+
            "Latitud2 = " + last_x +

            "Longitud2 = " + last_y+
            "j=" +j+
            "distance="+d3+" Speed  :  "+speed;

            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(speed>10)
            {
                TempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository =
                    new TempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository(getApplicationContext());
                tempTripJourneyWayPointsRepository.deleteTrip();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isTripPaused", false);
                editor.putBoolean("isTripStarted", true);
                editor.commit();
                insertWaypoint(loc);
                if(speed < 10.0)
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hoooo service"+speed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(isMyServiceRunning())
                    {
                        //trackingService.saveTripAsyncTask(getApplicationContext());
                        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //trackingScreenActivity.btnStop.performClick();
                        //trackingScreenActivity.stoptripinservice();

                        //      AddTripActivity.addTripActivity=

                        //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        //editor.putBoolean("isTripSaved", true);
                        //editor.commit();
                    }
                }

                last_x=loc.getLatitude();
                last_y=loc.getLongitude();
            }


        public  void editGenereateTripUniqueID(String uniqueId){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorUniqueID =
                TrackingService.context.getSharedPreferences("TripJouneryUID", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).edit();
            editorUniqueID.putString("UniqueIdForTrip", uniqueId);
            editorUniqueID.commit();
            //Log.v("Safecell : --UniqueIdForTrip", "ID = "+uniqueId);
        }

        private Double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
        {
            /* double theta = lon1 - lon2;
            double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) +
                          Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
            dist = Math.acos(dist);
            dist = rad2deg(dist);
            dist = dist * 60;
            dist = dist * 1852;*/
            double dlon = lon2 - lon1;
            double  dlat = lat2 - lat1;
            double a = Math.pow((Math.sin(dlat/2)),2) +
                       Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) *  Math.pow((Math.sin(dlon/2)),2);

            double c = 2 * Math.atan2( Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a) );
            double d = 6373  * c;
            return (d);
        }

        private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if ("com.safecell.TrackingService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int calcDistance(double latA, double longA, double latB, double longB) {

            double theDistance = (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latA)) *
                    Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latB)) +
                    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latA)) *
                    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latB)) *
                    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longA - longB)));

            return new Double((Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(theDistance))) * 69.09*1.6093).intValue();
        }

        private double deg2rad(double deg) {
            return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
        }

        private double rad2deg(double rad) {
            return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            // Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

        {
            // Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no confidence, but I have an idea.

1. You should set TIMEZONE_CHANGED 's broadcast. PF may reset Alarmmanager when changing date&Time. And Some Android devices defaults Date&Time setting is automatic!
2. You should write restart action code on Service#onCreate() from low memory killer. Maybe PF call `Service#onCreate()` when restarting your service. PF regist killed your service and restarted your service.
3. You may think about to execute your service as a foreground service. So killed priority/potential is low by low memory killer.
4. You may recheck your code about `NullPointerException` at `Service#onStart()`. PF might set null to onStart intent argument.
5. You may think on to set `PowerManager#WakeLock`. Service can not run when PF sleeps.

PS: you may check the following Android bugs about PowerManager and foreground service.

- *[WakeLock Timeout causes WakeLock under-locked on Timeout](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14184)*
- *[Notification won't be created as ongoing when starting foreground service](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20035)*

Comment: if you want to create situation that  low memory killer and reset AlarmManager. you try following

Comment: [Reset AlarmManager Test]. 1:off network. 2: off Data&Time's Automatic. 3:change date. but specific dependency deivce.

Comment: [Low Memory Kill Test] I recommend to use my application. this application create easily low memory state. https://github.com/kyorohiro/KyoroHelloAndroid/ KyoroStress.apk or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.kyorohiro.helloworld.stress